# Titanium geolocation tracking not work correctly

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, titanium, appcelerator

I'm building an app that needs to track location of user and I use

```
Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
Ti.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 0;
Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS
Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', locationChange);
```

On iOS when device is in the move the event is not fired regularly and when it's fired I dont have heading and speed ( even tested it on while driving )

```
...
heading : -1,
speed : -1
...
```

but if I run another navigation app  on background (like Plans) the event is fired constantly and I have  heading and speed of device, as if i'm only getting the events because the other apps.

its the same problem on android the event is not fired correctly

testing with ti SDK 5.1.2 and 5.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has tripped me up in the past. Add

   `Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST_FOR_NAVIGATION;`

Also note that very small numbers in the distance filter may cause some problems.

I use this

```
if (OS_IOS) {
  Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST_FOR_NAVIGATION;
  Ti.Geolocation.distanceFilter = Alloy.CFG.minUpdateDistance;
  Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS;
  Ti.Geolocation.pauseLocationUpdateAutomatically = true;
  Ti.Geolocation.activityType = Ti.Geolocation.ACTIVITYTYPE_OTHER_NAVIGATION;
} else { //Android  
  Ti.Geolocation.Android.manualMode = true;
  var gpsProvider = Ti.Geolocation.Android.createLocationProvider({
      name:              Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS,
      minUpdateTime:     Alloy.CFG.minAge / 1000,
      minUpdateDistance: Alloy.CFG.minUpdateDistance
  });

  var gpsRule = Ti.Geolocation.Android.createLocationRule({
      provider: Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS,
      accuracy: Alloy.CFG.accuracy,
      maxAge:   Alloy.CFG.maxAge,
      minAge:   Alloy.CFG.minAge,
  });

  Ti.Geolocation.Android.addLocationProvider(gpsProvider);
  Ti.Geolocation.Android.addLocationRule(gpsRule);
  Ti.Geolocation.Android.manualMode = true;
}
```

The Alloy.CFG settings are set in the config.json file.

```
{ 
 "global": {
   "minUpdateDistance": 10,
   "os:android": {
     "accuracy": 20,
     "minAge": 10000,
     "maxAge": 30000
    },...
```

Comment: when i just change the accuracy for iOS ACCURACY_BEST --> ACCURACY_BEST_FOR_NAVIGATION it's work correctly.


but I don't understand why ACCURACY_BEST It works before ?